# Liquibase sempre executando changesets

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

Olá, estou com um problema ao executar o Liquibase com Maven + Spring Boot. Ocorre o seguinte:

Tenho dois schemas, schema1 e schema2. No projeto, tenho 3 scripts em SQL nativo: primeiro cria os dois schema, depois crias as tabelas e terceiro popula os dados.

Mas sempre que faço um `mvn clean install` e depois `java -jar projeto-x-0.0.1.jar` ele diz nos logs que os schemas já existem. Mesmo tirando o sql que cria os schemas primeiro, o segundo script (que cria as tabelas) também dá erro.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para que quando eu subir o projeto, não executasse os mesmos changesets que já foram executados na primeira vez. (obs: as duas tabelas do liquibase, databasechangelog e databasechangeloglock, estão sendo criados no schema public)

**OBS**: Achei a causa: quando eu subo pela primeira vez, ele cria as tabelas databasechangelog e databasechangeloglock na public. Mas depois quando vou subir pela segunda vez ele cria no schema1. Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver:

Removi as dependências do maven referente ao Liquibase e adicionei o plugin ["Liquibase Maven Plugin"](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin)

Com isso, configurei normalmente conforme a documentação, dessa forma no pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>

  <configuration>
    <changeLogFile>db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
    <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:teste;shutdown=true</url>
    <username>seuusuario</username>
    <password></password>
    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <changelogSchemaName>public</changelogSchemaName>
    <defaultSchemaName>seuschema</defaultSchemaName>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

A mágica está nos atributos changelogSchemaName e defaultSchemaName. Onde o schemaName é onde ficará os dados de controle de versão do próprio Liquibase e defaultSchemaName é qual o schema padrão inicial.

Depois é só rodar `mvn clean package liquibase:update` que a mágica acontece.